# Reuse a variable used in Build periodically with parameters in Build periodically with parameters box itself

Tags: jenkins, build, parameters, scheduled-tasks, periodicity

I have below parameters

TZ=Asia/Kolkata
00 02 * * 1-5 %testEnv=company_name; ANSIBLE_BRANCH= develop; BRANCH=develop; copy_output_json_path=/config/di/**company_name**_otel.json; email=abc@pqr.com markers="";

Whenever there is change in **testEnv** variable I want it to get used in another variable name **copy_output_json_path**
So that I dont need to change it manually in every other variables where I need company_name value.

I am looking like something

00 02 * * 1-5 %testEnv=company_name; ANSIBLE_BRANCH= develop; BRANCH=develop; copy_output_json_path=/config/di/${testEnv}_otel.jso
n; email=abc@pqr.com markers="";

00 02 * * 1-5 %testEnv=company_name; ANSIBLE_BRANCH= develop; BRANCH=develop; copy_output_json_path=/config/di/**${testEnv}**_otel.jso
n; email=abc@pqr.com markers="";